# REST API generation for Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I tried to generate a REST API for my customers, categories, products, coupons, manufacturers and all others to use it in my Android application, but I can't get any solution.

Can anyone tell me how to create APIs in opencart 3.0.2.0?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is way too broad, you need to narrow it down to something specific. StackOverflow is not here to help you learn create API's, you should learn that by yourself.

Comment: yes, I know dear @FabianTjoeAOn. But i need only steps of Rest API configuration in opencart.

Comment: Then narrow your question down because it's hard to provide a solid answer this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom controller in  **catalog > Controller > api** folder

Create controller file name: `allproducts.php`

You can copy following code and paste of `allproducts.php`

```
<?php
class ControllerApiAllproducts extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    // All Products
    public function index(){
        $products = array();
        $this->load->language('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $error[]['no_json']= "No JSON";

        $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], 40, 40);
            } else {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 40, 40);
            }

            $special = false;

            $product_specials = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductSpecials($result['product_id']);

            foreach ($product_specials  as $product_special) {
                //if (($product_special['date_start'] == '0000-00-00' || strtotime($product_special['date_start']) < time()) && ($product_special['date_end'] == '0000-00-00' || strtotime($product_special['date_end']) > time())) {
                    $special = $product_special['price'];

                    //break;
               // }
            }

            $shop_products['shop_products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                'image'      => $image,
                'name'       => $result['name'],
                'model'      => $result['model'],
                'price'      => $result['price'],
                'special'    => $special,
                'quantity'   => $result['quantity'],
                'status'     => $result['status']
            );
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
            echo json_encode($shop_products);die;
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($error));
        }  
    }

    // Product info Page
    public function productInfo(){

        $this->load->language('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $product_details = array();
        $error['fail'] = 'Failed';

        if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            //$product_details['product_id'] = $this->request->get['product_id'];
            $product_details = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($this->request->get['product_id']);
            echo json_encode($product_details);die;
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($error));
        }
    }

    // Category Listing Page
    public function categories(){ 

        $shop_categories = array();
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $error['fail'] = 'Failed';

        if (isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
            $shop_categories =$this->model_catalog_category->getCategories();
            echo json_encode($shop_categories);die;
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($error));
        }
    }

    // Product Listing By Category
    public function categoryList(){ 

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $error['fail'] = 'Failed';

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url = '';
            $path = '';
            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

            $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

            foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
                if (!$path) {
                    $path = (int)$path_id;
                } else {
                    $path .= '_' . (int)$path_id;
                }

                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);
            }
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }

        $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

        if ($category_info) {

            $url = '';
            //$data['categories'] = array();
            $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $result['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

            }

            $products = array();

            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id' => $category_id
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);
            $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
            echo json_encode($products); die;

        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($error));
        }

    }

    // All Manufacturers Listing
    public function manufactureList() {

        $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $error['fail'] = 'Failed';

        $manufactureList = array();

        if (isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
            $manufactureList = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();
            echo json_encode($manufactureList);die;
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($error));
        }
    }

    // Manufactur info Page
    public function manufactureInfo() {

        $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $error['fail'] = 'Failed';

        if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $manufactureInfo = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($manufacturer_id);
            echo json_encode($product_details);die;
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($error));
        }
    }


    // Category Listing Page
    public function specialProduct(){ 

        $specialProduct = array();
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $error['fail'] = 'Failed';

        if (isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
            $specialProduct = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductSpecials();
            echo json_encode($specialProduct);die;
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($error));
        }
    }
}
```

I made following APIs and its path (see Postman apps):

> 1. ALL Products  : http://examples.com/index.php?route=api/allproducts&json
> 2. Product By ID : http://examples.com/index.php?route=api/allproducts/productInfo&json&product_id=30
> 3. ALL Categories : http://examples.com/index.php?route=api/allproducts/categories&json
> 4. Category Wise Product : http://examples.com/index.php?route=api/allproducts/categoryList&json&path=25_28
> 5. ALL Manufacturers : http://examples.com/index.php?route=api/allproducts/manufactureList&json
> 6. Manufactur By ID : http://examples.com/index.php?route=api/allproducts/manufactureInfo&manufacturer_id=11
> 7. Special Products : http://examples.com/index.php?route=api/allproducts/specialProduct&json

Comment: Please refrain from asking for upvotes in your posts. We want voting to be as organic here as possible: if your content is good then it will attract upvotes over the long term.